# ¿Como Puedo Incluir el valor de Mis TextBox al hacer una consulta SQL con C#?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp, webforms

Estoy tratando de crear unos reportes por fechas en ASP.Net Con crystal Report, pero no encuentro la forma de pasar los valores de mis TextBox en la consulta, dejo el código que tengo implementado.

Disculpen pero estoy iniciando en esto :)

```
 SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection("Data Source=LARSDESKTOP\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=LibreriaPrueba;Integrated Security=true");
        DataSet1 datos = new DataSet1();
        string sql = "select  Ingreso.IdIngreso, ingreso.Fecha, Proveedor.Nombre as 'Nombre Proveedor', Ingreso.Total from Ingreso inner join Proveedor on Ingreso.IdProveedor = Proveedor.IdProveedor where Fecha  BETWEEN @fechaInicio and @fechaFinal";

        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, conexion);
        adapter.Fill(datos.ReporteFactura);
        CrystalReportCompras reporte = new CrystalReportCompras();
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = reporte;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es fácil, se trata de formar la sentencia SQL concatenando o bien usando reemplazar.

```
 SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection("Data 
 Source=LARSDESKTOP\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=LibreriaPrueba;Integrated Security=true");
 DataSet1 datos = new DataSet1();
 string sql = "SELECT Ingreso.IdIngreso, ingreso.Fecha, " + 
                     "Proveedor.Nombre AS 'Nombre Proveedor', Ingreso.Total " +
              "FROM Ingreso " +
              "INNER JOIN Proveedor ON Ingreso.IdProveedor = Proveedor.IdProveedor " +
              "WHERE Fecha  BETWEEN '@fechaInicio' and '@fechaFinal'";

 sql = sql.Replace("@fechaInicio", textBox1.Text);
 sql = sql.Replace("@fechaFinal", textBox2.Text);
```

Con esto habrás logrado que en la cadena sql se haya sustituido @fechaInicio por lo que contiene el control textBox1 y @fechaFinal por lo que contiene el textBox2.
Observa que en la cadena sql inicial he añadido comillas simple enmarcando las fechas.

Comment: Muchas Gracias Antonio, me Funciono tu respuesta. :D

Answer (score 1):

tambien puedes hacerlo asi, si entendi es mandar la informacion de lo que tienes desde tu textbox y guardarlo a la base de datos
algo importante estoy utilizando la programacion en ncapas, sino lo estas haciendo asi debes adaptarlo atu codigo

```
 /****************************************
     MEDTODO INSERTAR PRODUCTOS
    *****************************************/
            public void cd_InsertarProducto(string codigoBarra, string nombProducto, string desProducto, int estadoProducto, int idMarca, int idCategoria, int idUnidadMedida, string rutaimg)
            {
               
 using (var connection = GetConnection())
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (var command = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    command.Connection = connection;
                    command.CommandText = "insert into tproducto (codigoBarra,nombProducto,desProducto,estadoProducto,idMarca,idCategoria,idUnidadMedida,rutaimg) " +
                                         " values (@codigoBarra,@nombProducto,@desProducto,@estadoProducto,@idMarca,@idCategoria,@idUnidadMedida,@rutaimg) ";

                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codigoBarra",codigoBarra);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombProducto",nombProducto);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@desProducto",desProducto);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@estadoProducto",estadoProducto);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idMarca",idMarca);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idCategoria",idCategoria);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idUnidadMedida",idUnidadMedida);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rutaimg", rutaimg);

                    command.CommandType=CommandType.Text;
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                     
                }
            }
        }
```

si es que vas a mandar la que tienes en tu tabla al formulario y llenar tus textbox pues lo haces asi, hago la consulta de lo que querio mostrar.esto para la capa datos

```
 /****************************************
     MEDTODO LISTAR PRODUCTOS
 *****************************************/
        public DataTable cd_ListarProducto()
        {
            using (var connection = GetConnection())
            {
                SqlDataReader xReader;
                DataTable xDataTable = new DataTable();

                connection.Open();

                using (var command = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    command.Connection = connection;
                    command.CommandText = "select codigoBarra AS CODIGO, "+
                                       "nombProducto AS PRODUCTO, "+
                                       "desProducto AS DESCRIPCION, "+
                                       "estadoProducto AS ESTADO, "+
                                       "tmarca.nombreMarca AS MARCA, "+
                                       "tcategoria.nombreCategoria AS CATEGORIA, "+
                                       "tUnidadMedida.nombUnidadMedida AS UNIDADMEDIDA "+
                                       "FROM tproducto "+ 
                                       "INNER JOIN tmarca on tproducto.idMarca=tmarca.marcaId "+
                                       "INNER JOIN tcategoria on tproducto.idCategoria=tcategoria.categoriaId " +
                                       "INNER JOIN tUnidadMedida on tproducto.idUnidadMedida=tUnidadMedida.umId ";
                    xReader = command.ExecuteReader();
                    xDataTable.Load(xReader);

                    return xDataTable;
                }
            }
        }
```

para la capamodelo.

```
 /****************************************
      MEDTODO LISTAR PRODUCTOS DG
  *****************************************/
    ProductoModel xxProductoModel = new ProductoModel();
            public DataTable cdo_listarProductos()
            {
                DataTable xDataTable = new DataTable();
                xDataTable = xProductosDatos.cd_ListarProducto();
                return xDataTable;
            }
```

esto en la capa presentacion en los formularios
aqui algo importante estoy mandando a colocar todo dentro de un datagridview toda la informacion que traigo de la bd y cuando ago clic en el la celda del datagrid llena todoslos textbox

```
 /****************************************
 METODO LISTAR PRODUCTOS EN DGVProducto 
     CUENDO CARGA EL FORMULARIO
 *****************************************/
    ProductosDatos xProductosDatos = new ProductosDatos();

                public void xlistarproducto()
                {
                   dgv1Productos.DataSource= xxProductoModel.cdo_listarProductos();
                }
        
                /****************************************
                 MEDTODO CARGAR PRODUCTO EN TEXTBOX AL 
                 HACER CLICK EN DATAGRIDVIEW
                *****************************************/
                private void dgv1Productos_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
                {
                    if (dgv1Productos.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
                    {

        
                        txtcodigoProducto.Text = dgv1Productos.CurrentRow.Cells["CODIGO"].Value.ToString();
                        txtnombreProducto.Text = dgv1Productos.CurrentRow.Cells["PRODUCTO"].Value.ToString();
                        chkestadoProducto.Text = dgv1Productos.CurrentRow.Cells["ESTADO"].Value.ToString();
                        cboCategoriaProducto.Text = dgv1Productos.CurrentRow.Cells["CATEGORIA"].Value.ToString();
                        cboMarcaProducto.Text = dgv1Productos.CurrentRow.Cells["MARCA"].Value.ToString();
                        cboUMProducto.Text = dgv1Productos.CurrentRow.Cells["UNIDADMEDIDA"].Value.ToString();
txtdesProducto.Text = dgv1Productos.CurrentRow.Cells["DESCRIPCION"].Value.ToString();
rutaimagtxt.Text = dgv1Productos.CurrentRow.Cells["RUTAIMAGEN"].Value.ToString();
    
}
```